# I am a bit confused about my research design. If anyone would be willing to give some feedback, I would be very appreciative

Tags: thesis

I'm currently writing my Bachelors thesis in communicational studies, but I am confused about the aspect of research design. I believe my paper has a bit of both qualitative and quantitative characteristics, and I'd love some feedback.

To outline my plan:

1. I am looking for two types of framing in tweets: a) framing of the problem, and b) framing of the action to solve the problem. While the specific content I am looking for is theory-based (theoretical framework says that this kind of framing will occur), the specific framing categories that emerge are not. In that regard, I am letting the categories and the overall answers to my research question emerge from the data. **Can I confidently say that this is inductive research?**
2. Next up, after having determined the framing categories present, I will put them in a table to find out the frequencies of each kind of framing. Now, while I think the first part of this was qualitative, as it was essentially a content analysis (?), looking at frequencies hints me towards a quantitative approach. And at the end of my paper, I am conducting a chi-square analysis of whether the variables of "framing of problem" and "framing of action" is related or independent. **This is also very quantitative, correct?**
   So to recap: I seem to be doing a content analysis (looking into tweets for framing categories), but then I'm looking at the frequency and doing a chi-square analysis of the two variables. Would I be calling this a quantitative study then, or is it rather a mixed study?

Oh, and if I may ask a follow-up question - last one, I promise - **is this type of approach compatible with social constructivism?** - Which is the philosophy of science that I personally "believe in" and fits the whole topic of framing.

It got a bit long, sorry about that!
I appreciate any help that I may get. Thank you!

Comment: You should speak with your supervisor. This forum is for asking about general academia related questions, not discipline specific research question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry about that. It's not possible to speak with my supervisor. She's not arranging anymore supervision hours, and I didn't initially expect to run into this problem, as I've changed my research design slightly since then. Anyway, I'll try to figure out something.